# re: remove string in brackets and its whitespace

Tags: regex, pandas, apply, data-cleaning

what's the best `re` way to remove brackets and their content, as well as the trailing whitespace within a string? Note that not every string is formatted equally.

**Script:**

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'name':
          ['University of Southampton (UK)', 
          'The College of William and Mary', 
          'University of Reading (UK)', 
          'Queensland University (Australia)']})

def cleaning(text):
    cleaned = re.findall(re.compile('^([^,]+).+'), text)
    cleaned = re.findall(re.compile('\(.*\)'), str(cleaned)) # Why do I have to str() here btw?
    return cleaned

df['name'].apply(lambda x: cleaning(x))
```

**Returns:**

```
0    []
1    []
2    []
3    []
```

**Desired output (no whitespace at the end):**

```
0    University of Southampton
1    The College of William and Mary
2    University of Reading
3    Queensland University
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace(r'\s*\([^()]*\)', '')`

Comment: What would be the best way to wrap that into the function above? I tried to add 'cleaned = re.sub('\s*\([^()]*\)', '', str(cleaned))' without success.

Comment: Why do you need that? `df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace(r'\s*\([^()]*\)', '')` works as is. `def cleaning(text):
    return re.sub(r'\s*\([^()]*\)', '', text)` works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only work for this specific case, but you can do

```
df.name.str.split('\(',expand=True)[0].str.strip()
```