# How does one, within a string, remove an entire character sequence that uses brackets as delimiters (including the brackets)?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

In order to illustrate/visualize my problem I do provide following 3 examples of possible input values each followed by its expected result ...

```
"[New] Awesome Product" ===> "Awesome Product"
"[bla bla] Awesome Product" ===> "Awesome Product"
"Awesome Product [abcd]" ===> "Awesome Product"
```

I want to remove everything that is *"written"* inside brackets including the brackets itself (and some optional whitespaces before and after the latter).

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Note: The code is using an anti-pattern. Don't use `map` if you don't use the array it returns. Use `for-of` or `for` or `forEach`.

Comment: you can use `string.replace("[New]", '').replace("(10% off)", "")` to achieve what you want

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507607/re-remove-string-in-brackets-and-its-whitespace

Comment: @japrescott The string inside of bracket not specified. I added more examples.

Comment: @Barmar That looks not JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) when using the [string.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function.

eg.

```
string = string.replace(/\[.+?\]/igm, '') // replace [text]
string = string.replace(/\(.+?\)/igm, '') // replace (text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
"Awesome Product [abcd]".replace(/[\[|\(].+[\]|\)]/g, '')
```